# Simple way to check if input is in focus and to disable mouseleave function if true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to admit that I'm definitely no jQuery genius but what seems like  asimple solution has just totally eluded me.

Basically I have a drop down script working on a nested ul to display on rollover of its parent. In one of the nested ul I have a form that I would like to stop the mouseleave event if any of the inputs in the form are being entered into.

Here's the original code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

/*------- navigation -------*/
$('.top_menu li').hover(function(){
    var index = $('.top_menu li').index(this);
    if($(this).children('ul').length != 0)
    {
        $(this).children('ul').show();
    }
});
$('.top_menu li').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
}); 


$('.login_cart li,.login_cart_captu li').hover(function(){
    var index = $('.login_cart li').index(this);
    if($(this).children('ul').length != 0)
    {
        $(this).children('ul').show();
    }
});

$('.login_cart li,.login_cart_captu li').mouseleave(function(){

        $(this).children('ul').hide();

});

});
```

I'm really only concerned with the .login_cart li portion of the script - that's the only one that has the form within it.

I've tried with a simple if/else statement to not hide if an input has focus but that hasn't worked so far.

Any help anyone could give me or to shed some light on this would be absolutely wonderful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set a global variable with the input's onfocus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind the [focus event](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) of the form elements to a function that [unbinds](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the mouseleave event from the .login_cart li:

```
$("#<form-id> input").focus(function() {
    $(".login_cart li, .login_cart_captu li").unbind("mouseleave");
}
```

You'll just have to replace  with the id of your form or you can use whatever selector you want to select your form.

Comment: This worked to a point - thanks! Just one small question - if a person clicks out of the form (say they didn't really want to sign in after all) the drop down stays open. Is there a way to incorporate into an if/else or to use maybe .bind() to ensure the default closing function still happens if the inputs lose their focus? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: try using the blur event http://api.jquery.com/blur/

You can hide the form in this event. You'll probably want to rebind the mouseleave event here as well.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.6 and newer has :focus built in. Not tested with .not(), but have tested this with a ! in front and .is(":focus"), just looked nicer with .not(); but both should do the same.

```
 $('.login_cart li,.login_cart_captu li').mouseleave(function(){
       if ($("#<form-id> input").not(":focus")) {
           $(this).children('ul').hide();
       }
 });
```